# Spring Cloud Data Flow urlExpression of httpclient cannot be set properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I parse image urls from JSON produced by Twitter with Spring Cloud Data Flow and I'd like to download the image with `httpclient`.

Here is the pipeline:

```
twitterstream --twitter.credentials.consumerKey=*** --twitter.credentials.consumerSecret=*** --twitter.credentials.accessToken=*** --twitter.credentials.accessTokenSecret=*** | splitter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.entities.media[*].media_url') | httpclient --httpclient.httpMethod=GET --httpclient.urlExpression=payload | log
```

If I exclude the `httpclient` the following log appears in the log, therefore I suppose the url extraction is successful and the `httpclient` gets the url.

```
2019-12-21 12:46:23.120  INFO 1 --- [container-0-C-1] log-sink                                 : http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EMBcr-XVAAARY7x.png
```

I get the following exception from the `httpclient` (URI is not absolute)

```
2019-12-21 19:17:06.741 ERROR 1 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.LoggingErrorHandler   : Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = test.splitter, partition = 0, offset = 74, CreateTime = 1576954352460, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 87, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = sequenceNumber, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = sequenceSize, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = deliveryAttempt, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = scst_nativeHeadersPresent, value = [116, 114, 117, 101]), RecordHeader(key = correlationId, value = [34, 56, 98, 57, 100, 56, 99, 57, 99, 45, 49, 100, 52, 50, 45, 55, 97, 101, 54, 45, 50, 54, 49, 55, 45, 50, 98, 102, 52, 101, 51, 100, 99, 98, 57, 55, 50, 34]), RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [34, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110, 34]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 115, 99, 115, 116, 95, 110, 97, 116, 105, 118, 101, 72, 101, 97, 100, 101, 114, 115, 80, 114, 101, 115, 101, 110, 116, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 66, 111, 111, 108, 101, 97, 110, 34, 44, 34, 115, 101, 113, 117, 101, 110, 99, 101, 83, 105, 122, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 100, 101, 108, 105, 118, 101, 114, 121, 65, 116, 116, 101, 109, 112, 116, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 110, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 46, 97, 116, 111, 109, 105, 99, 46, 65, 116, 111, 109, 105, 99, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 114, 114, 101, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 85, 85, 73, 68, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@73d60921)

org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[87], headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceSize=1, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedTopic=test.splitter, kafka_offset=74, scst_nativeHeadersPresent=true, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@103e165f, correlationId=8b9d8c9c-1d42-7ae6-2617-2bf4e3dcb972, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1576954352460}]
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:369) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$400(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:74) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:431) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:402) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:3.1.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211) ~[spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1278) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1261) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1222) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1203) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1123) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:938) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:751) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:700) [spring-kafka-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.8.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:111) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:113) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
        at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:145) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:87) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:731) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:637) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.httpclient.processor.HttpclientProcessorFunctionConfiguration.lambda$httpRequest$0(HttpclientProcessorFunctionConfiguration.java:102) ~[spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-httpclient-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.7.RELEASE]
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

I think the problem is with the `--httpclient.urlExpression=payload` parameter, where I try to reference the url by the `payload` keyword. What's the problem exactly?

**UPDATE:**
I think the problem is that the `payload` is a series of ASCII character codes. How can I create a string from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `payload` is a series of ASCII codes and I solved the issue by setting `--httpclient.urlExpression='new String(payload)'`. It converts the ASCII codes to a string, but I think it's not the best solution so I'm waiting for a better one.